# Boundedness of solutions of Difference equation

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, recurrence-relations

Consider a second order difference equation in complex plane, \begin{equation}
z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha + \beta z_{n}}{1+z_{n-1}},\qquad n=0,1,\ldots
\end{equation}

where the parameters $\alpha, ~\beta$ are complex numbers, and the initial conditions $z_{-1}$ and $z_{0}$ are arbitrary complex numbers.

How to prove that the sequence $\{z_n\}_n$ is bounded?

Comment: What happens if $z_{-1}=-1$ or if $z_0=-1$...

Comment: We can exclude $z_{-1}=-1$.

Comment: Don't you try induction?

Comment: Could you please enlighten in more detail?? I tried but failed.

Comment: OK, let us exclude $z_{-1}=-1$. But what happens if $\beta\ne\alpha$, $z_{-1}=\beta-\alpha-1$ and $z_0=1$? I am afraid this question is incomplete.

Comment: Did, if we can also talk about boundedness with some conditions, that is highly acceptable too. The conditions you have mentioned, we can respect them and try to show boundedness.

Comment: You are not getting the point of our comments: what happens if somebody provides **other** initial conditions such that the sequence is not even defined? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: Of course we must talk about boundedness only if the sequence is well defined.